# cocas2d particles in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, particle-system

I have a particle system up and running on my iphone simulator, however there is one issue. I am creating a card game and wish to have the particle effect under the cards, currently the particles are overlapping and going over the cards on display which does not look so great.
How do i achieve the desired effect?

here is my code in the init section

```
- (id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {         
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        **[self configureEmitter];**    

        [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB565];
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"myBackground.png"];
        background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:background];
        [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_Default];    
    }
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    return self;
}

- (void)configureEmitter {
    self.emitter = [[CCParticleSystemQuad alloc] initWithTotalParticles:100];
    self.emitter.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"particlespng"];
    [self.emitter setEmitterMode:kCCParticleModeGravity];   
    emitter.duration = -1;
    emitter.gravity = ccp(-200, -80);
}
```

Comment: Use the z order to put the particles under the card.

Comment: thanks for the response, for the most part it worked, however only after i omitted the code that adds the background. The background is important and i will need to re add it, how do i add the particle effect in the back whilst keeping the particles in the back? This is what i did: 1) omitted code adding background image 2) set emitter z order to 0 as follows  [self addChild: emitter z:0];

Comment: got it working: set the z order of background to 0 then emitter to 1 and finally the sprites to 2, gracias Emilio!